# pytest assertion message not displayed in helper function within same test module in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, pytest

I'm seeing that assertion messages do not seem to be displayed if the assertion occurs in a helper method within the same module as my test when in PyCharm.

This only seems to be happening in PyCharm - it does not happen when running from the command line.

This works:

```
def test_assertion_message_working():
  assert 1 == 2, "my message"
```

```
Expected :2
Actual :1
...
def test_assertion_message_working():
> assert 1 ==2, "my message"
```

But this doesn't (the test fails, but I do not get the failure message):

```
def test_assertion_message_not_working():
  do_assertion()

def do_assertion():
  assert 1 == 2, "my message"
```

```
1 != 2

Expected :2 
Actual :1
...
def test_assertion_not_working():
>  do_assertion()
```

Wondering if there is any setting (or workaround) I need to apply to get this working?

Comment: this is an actual issue in pycharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50396

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on *PyCharm Build #PC-222.4345.23, built on October 10, 2022*
and it shows failure message in console. I do not have any specific settings on the project level defined in *pytest.ini* or *setup.cfg* config files.
[image]

Comment: I am reproducing this exact problem in Pycharm Build #PC-232.10227.11, built on November 13, 2023.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround though it makes the code a bit more verbose.

```
def test_assertion_message_not_working():
  do_assertion()

def do_assertion():
  if not(1 == 2):
    pytest.fail("my message")
```

Which does give the full context information when run in pycharm